# to request user `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` without displaying the permission management screen

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I am wandering if there is a way to request user `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` without displaying the permission management screen.

**For example :** prompt a dialog box to user to grant this permission.

Comment: Please explain in details,
No need overlay permission in playstore version because, in playstore app version, OVERLAY permission is enabled.

Comment: i never published an app on google play, so i don't know it is enabled in playstore. But in the app i need this permission. I think i got my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is placed in Google Play you don't need to request this permission (if it was fresh install), because it will be automatically granted.

> Every app that requests the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and that is
>   installed through the Play Store (version 6.0.5 or higher is
>   required), will have the permission granted automatically for the app.

Otherwise you should show the settings screen to the user to handle this permission.

Comment: Thank you, but the second part of your answer confuses me. I think my question doesn't have anything to do with `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission.

Comment: ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION 
Activity Action: Show screen for controlling which apps can draw on top of other apps (And also you need SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in your manifest to handle this).  @Keyum

Comment: Thank you, I am new to android.